# Value in stack gets overwritten

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit, windbg, stack-corruption

I have a C++ program that reports a crash. Analyzing it further, I am able to figure out the exact place where the data on stack gets corrupted. But, I am not able to understand why that happens or what would cause such corruption. At a point in time

value at `[rsp+40h]` is `00000249 15ed4de0`

Then the following assembly instruction gets executed
`mov     rsi,qword ptr [rsp+40h]`

Now, the value at
`[rsp+40h]` is `00000000 15ed4de0`

The higher order DWORD has changed from `00000249` to `00000000`. There are no changes in the addresses nearby. I do not understand why a read from `[rsp+40h]` would end up corrupting the value present at that address.

Any pointers are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you have a C++ program, but you are showing assembly language.  Let's look at the C++ code, instead of trying to figure out what the assembly language is doing.  Obviously either your higher-level (C++) code has corrupted data in some way, or much less likely, the code generated by the compiler is faulty.

Comment: Also a reproducable example would be helpful.

Comment: What's in `rsi` before & after that instruction?

Comment: `mov     rsi,qword ptr [rsp+40h]` is a pure load; it doesn't modify memory.  If memory contents are changing, definitely some other instruction is responsible.  (Or inter-process memory modification via a system call or shared memory, or another thread in the same process).  Set a watch-point on the address.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, it is quite a lengthy C++ function and adding it here is not possible. But this does not happen when any visible code is executing, but during the function epilogue, when the local objects are getting destroyed.

  @ErikEidt, 
rsi value, 
before `0x00000249 15ed4de0`
after   `0x00000000 15ed4de0`

  @JakobStark, Its quite hard to reproduce and it happens very inconsistently.

Comment: I agree to @PeterCordes: set a memory breakpoint usig `ba`.

Comment: when moving from mem to register changes to mem should not  happen run  ? poi(@rsp+40) ; t; ?poi(@rsp+4)  in windbg  not p or g  0:000> rM0
00007fff`1bd1f263 488b5c2440      mov     rbx,qword ptr [rsp+40h] ss:000000dd`4ec8f150=0000000000000010
0:000> ? poi(@rsp+40); t ; ? poi(@rsp+40)
Evaluate expression: 16 = 00000000`00000010
Evaluate expression: 16 = 00000000`00000010
0:000> rM0
00007fff`1bd1f268 33c0            xor     eax,eax

Comment: @Senthil *But this does not happen when any visible code is executing* -- Which can also mean that your program corrupted memory somewhere else, and the site of the crash is where everything has finally broken down.  Even if this were not assembly language and just C++, a C++ programmer would not concentrate on the code where the crash occurs.  TBH, focusing on where the crash occurs isn't going to help to a great extent.  You have to look at the C++ code itself in its entirety, and identify where undefined behavior can occur, or memory corruption.

Comment: @Senthil *It is quite a lengthy C++ function* -- That makes my comments more relevant.  There is a much greater chance that the large function or callers to that function corrupted memory.